# Resolving Issue with "Copy of a Slice from a DataFrame"

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, append

below is a code snipped, I like to explain alongside with comments. The main purpose of the script: Open/create a csv and continue a script at the last position. While the script is running, make sure to write row by row into the Dataframe, so that none of the processed data is being lost.

```
data = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=',')

...

with open('output.csv', 'a+') as f:

# Continue script where it stopped last
pos = len(f.readlines()[1:])
data = data.iloc[pos:]

try:
    # Get two values from a function, write into two columns
    # progress_apply shows the progress (can be improved though)
    data[['city', 'country']] = data.progress_apply(func, axis=1, result_type='expand')
    # Append data to output.csv, but only add header for first entry
    data.to_csv(f, mode='a', header=f.tell()==0, encoding='utf-8', index=False)

except:
    print('Error at position {}.'.format(pos))
    pass
```

When the script finished processing, it prints:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

How can I resolve the issue, i.e. what's wrong with the code?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a warning due to the positional argument and is causing a chained assignment, typically, the warning indicates that operation might not have worked as expected. You can set the warning off by adding the following line right before the loc[:],

```
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
```

Comment: Okay, so I would then suppress the warning. But can I be sure that the operation is okay, or is there a better way? The output.csv looks good. Also it's 'iloc', not 'loc', if that's important. I thought the mistake might be exactly in there.

Comment: For me the code that you wrote looks good, the iloc expects a columnindex to be 100% sure, but in your case you are adding a row after the last row, so should be good according to me. Also, are you trying to add delta data to the read dataframe?

Comment: Excuse, what is 'delta data'? But yes, checked the output and everything looks good.

Comment: I meant incremental data